# Turtlesim Give a New Goal Position

Tags: ros

I'm learning how to move turtle in Turtlesim. I'm trying to give a new goal and restart move to goal position function while turtle is going to different goal position.

My code is here:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy
from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist
from turtlesim.msg import Pose
import math
import time

x = 0
y = 0
yaw = 0

def takepose(pose_message):
    global x, y, yaw
    x = pose_message.x
    y = pose_message.y
    yaw = pose_message.theta


def go_to_goalpose(x_goal, y_goal):
    global x, y, yaw
    
    velocity_message = Twist()

    while True:
        K_linear = 0.5
        distance = abs(math.sqrt((((x_goal - x) ** 2) + ((y_goal - y) ** 2))))

        linear_speed = distance * K_linear

        K_angular = 4.0
        desired_angle_goal = math.atan2(y_goal - y, x_goal-x)
        angular_speed = (desired_angle_goal - yaw) * K_angular

        velocity_message.linear.x = linear_speed
        velocity_message.angular.z = angular_speed

        velocity_publisher.publish(velocity_message)

        if (distance <= 0.01):
            break

    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        rospy.init_node("turtlesim_motion_pose", anonymous=True)

        cmd_vel_topic = "/turtle1/cmd_vel"
        velocity_publisher = rospy.Publisher(cmd_vel_topic, Twist, queue_size=10)

        position_topic = "/turtle1/pose"
        pose_subscriber = rospy.Subscriber(position_topic, Pose, takepose)
        time.sleep(2)

        go_to_goalpose(0.0, 0.0)

    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        rospy.loginfo("node terminated")
```

How can I give a new goal and restart go_to_goalpose function while function is working.

**Souliton**

In this link, It tells how to do.

http://wiki.ros.org/turtlesim/Tutorials/Go%20to%20Goal

Answer (score 0):

Because you are doing the `while True` inside `go_to_goalpose`, I don't think you could actually do that. You could implement this function as a callback like `takepose_and_move` that would actually be called whenever you receive a msg on the topic '/turtle1/pose' and publish the velocity. In that case, you would only move as long as you are still receiving the message.

Comment: I solved my problem with using threading but actually it isn't what I want. I want to publish  my goal position and move turtle to there. Do you have any expamle code or source? If you have, can you share with me?

Comment: what do you think about using a ros service instead of  a ros publisher?

Comment: I found it. It my fault that I didn't search it enough.

Comment: Those are good news. I am glad you found it. Maybe you should also take a look at `TransformListener`